# Escaped \` works in comment, but not answer

Tags: bug, markdown, formatting

In the question & answer editor, the input:

```
`\``
```

produces the output:
```

Whereas in the comments, the same string correctly renders a code block containing a back-tick.

Comment: Block (evidently no-op in comments): ```
`\``
```, standalone code-quoted:
`\``

Comment: Since this is a network wide feature it's better to post it in [meta.se].